# How can you force programmers to not initialise empty objects?

Tags: c++, object, constructor, initialization

If i want to force other programmers to not initialise empty objects in a custom class of mine, what can I do to achieve this?

Im guessing it has something to do with constructors but im just not a 100% sure.

Comment: The question is quite vague... could you give a code example of the behavior you want to avoid?

Comment: What's an empty object?

Comment: Parametrized constructor?

Comment: I'm guessing you either _do_ want uninitialized member variables or you _do not_ want uninitialized member variables. From you question it is not clear.

Comment: If you don't provide any methods to initialise empty objects (whatever you might mean by that), then you force clients to not initialise any empty objects thiey might have. But maybe you wanted to ask a different question?

Comment: Better post this in [workplace.se]?

Comment: @sashoalm: No, as a library writer such things can be valid concerns. And then those programmers are your customers, not your colleagues.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 onwards you can `delete` the default constructor. If your class is named `Foo`, use

`Foo() = delete;`

You'll need to provide an alternative way of constructing the object though. (Supplying an alternative constructor implicitly deletes the default one but being explicit about this can make your code clearer).

(Pre C++11, you could declare the default constructor to be `private` and not supply a definition. Its attempted use would cause compiler and linker errors.)

Comment: Whenever you explicitly define _any_ constructor, the default constructor is no longer implicitly defined (this has always been the case). There is no need to explicitly delete the default constructor.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, True, but it is a nice way of documenting that you did it on purpose.

Comment: Indeed. I point that out in my answer.

Comment: The private undefined default ctor was a bad idea in C++98. As Marc van Leeuwen correctly pointed out, if you didn't even declare it, the error would always be caught at compile time. By declaring it, you delay definition errors until link time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an object with un-initialized member variables (this is how I interpret "empty objects"), then you should build a constructor which forces those members to null.

```
class Bar
{
    int* mem1;        
    int* mem2;

    Bar()
    {
        mem1=nullptr;
        mem2=nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `nullptr` (C++11) or `NULL` (C++98) not `null`

Answer (score 1):

If by **empty**, you meant not passing any parameters during object creation,
then just make your constructor accept a certain value (wihtout any defaults)

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the number of objects instantiation can be done by using variation of singleton pattern.